# New to OSX and commands are never found so I 'export' them. Is there a way to fix it for good?

Tags: macos, bash, path, export, profile

I'm new to bash and my Mac (about a week) and only 3 months into programming. I've been running into this problem where it ends up being something in my bash profile.

Like changing environment variables in my python so commands like

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH”

export DATABASE_URL=“postgresql://localhost/CHEESE”

export APP_SETTINGS=“config.DevelopmentConfig"
```

or to get my Postgres in python to work I have to do this

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/:$PATH
```

recently I just installed virtualenvwrapper and had to do a sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper and running the code in bash would not find it unless I did this

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

So I did some research and I THINK I can permanatly add them to my 'bash profile'. If this is the case I have 2 questions.

1. Is there a way I can avoid having to manually add the exports in the first place. So I can have the commands working right after installing
2. How do I add them to my profile. I opened my .bash_profile.swp and it looked intimidating so I didn't touch it because I thought I'd break it. I'm not sure why I had a random pathing for my psycopg2 at the end of the line either( seen in the second link)
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzXvj.jpg
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXtcI.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Adding these to your `.bash_profile` will set the environment variables every time you start up your shell. However, as explained [here](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html), it is better to put them in your `.bashrc` and then source that from your `.bash_profile`. For example,

```
# put this in your .bashrc
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH"
export DATABASE_URL="postgresql://localhost/CHEESE"
export APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"
# etc...

# then put this in your .bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

This ensures the variables are properly set no matter how you start your shell. The `.swp` file you are seeing is created by Vim. Just ignore it.

However, *there is a better way*. The easiest and cleanest way to install software on your computer is with a package manager, which will automatically set the paths for you (among other things). For Mac, I recommend using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Once you install it, you can do things like

```
$ brew install ruby
$ ruby blah blah blah  # ruby gets put in the PATH for you!
```

For python, the standard package manager is `pip`, which you are already using. However, a word of advice: `sudo pip` installs packages for the python 2 that comes as part of OS X, which from personal experience I recommend not doing. Instead, install python 2 with Homebrew, and then use the pip (and the python) that comes with that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with homebrew. I installed python with it and will see how it goes.